# WCF connection returns an exception sometimes?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, wcf, azure

I have a WCF service running on Azure. Basically what it does is connect to a MySQL database. The database is created using Entity Framework 6.0 code-first approach. Everything works fine. Except sometimes I get this exception:

> TestProject.TestW2E.GetSalt:
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]
>   : An error occurred accessing the database. This usually means that
>   the connection to the database failed. Check that the connection
>   string is correct and that the appropriate DbContext constructor is
>   being used to specify it or find it in the application's config file.
>   See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386386 for information on
>   DbContext and connections. See the inner exception for details of the
>   failure.

If I try running again it disappears and everything works fine or sometimes it comes back. There is no inner exception. The exception tells me that there is something wrong with my `DbContext` constructor. The constructor looks fine to me :

```
public Model1(): base("name=DbModel")
{
}
```

I checked my connection string to in `web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="DbModel" 
         connectionString="password=secretpassword;user id=username;persistsecurityinfo=True;server=w2itestserver.cloudapp.net;database=db;" 
         providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```