# Exception : 'The underlying provider failed on open' when I call method from wcf service

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, azure

I have a WCF service running on Azure. When I call a method of that service it gives me sometimes an exception back :

> The underlying provider failed on open

The exception appears and disappears. There is no inner exception.

In my testing environment where I use iis everything works perfect.

My connection string :

```
<add name="DbModel" 
     connectionString="password=secretpassword;user id=username;persistsecurityinfo=True;server=w2itestserver.cloudapp.net;database=db;" 
     providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

Comment: You should change connection string to the one provided by the database hosted in Azure or on an external host.

Comment: Is this (still) the same issue as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28252021/21567) one you asked 4 hours ago? If so, consider updating your original question, rather than asking a new one.

Comment: @Christian.K No not the same issue, I managed to solve that one.Should I consider deleting my previous question ?

Comment: @NikolayKostov Thanks for the hint about the connection string. I formulated it like this : Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword; . It works like a charm for now

Comment: @nutellaFreak if you solved the issue in a previous question you should go and add your solution as the answer. This will help other people who have the same of similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1. Open Internet Information Service Manager
2. Click on Application Pools in left navigation tree.
3. Select your version Pool. In my case, I am using ASP .Net v4.0. If you dont have this version, select DefaultAppPool.
4. Right click on step 3, and select advanced settings.
5. Select Identity in properties window and click the button to change the value.
6. Select Local System in Built-in accounts combo box and click ok.

That's it. Now run your application.may be Everything works well.